# change the date format of a column in all sheets of a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to change a custom date format to dd/mm/yyyy.
The code below works for the current worksheet but wont work for all worksheets.

```
Sub dateformat()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

   For Each ws In Worksheets
        Columns("E:E").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
        'MsgBox ws.Name
    Next ws

End Sub
```

its hard to manually run the macro per column as the workbook has 100+ sheets.
any thoughts on how i can get this to work?

Comment: If you're iterating using `ws`, you should probably use it (as in `ws.Columns`).

Comment: edited as you suggested but i got an "invalid use of property" error

Comment: `ws.Columns("E:E").Select` works just fine here. Where do you get the "invalid use of proprty errror?

Comment: i get a "run time error '1004' " : select method of range class failed". `ws.Columns("E:E").Select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub dateformat()

Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Avoid selecting, it's unreliable and unnecessary.  Also "worksheets" should have a workbook.

Comment: thanks!
it seems that select slows down code too. with your suggestion it was noticeably much faster